# How to get colours to appear on map in Vega-Lite?

Tags: visualization, vega-lite

I have a map of the world to display road deaths in each country. I'm trying to create a choropleth map, where the shade of the colour is dependant on the amount of deaths in that country. The figures are showing in the tooltip when hovering over the country, and in the legend, but it isn't changing the colour of the country on the map.

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  "title": {
    "text": "Worldwide Deaths on Roads per 100k inhabitants",
    "fontSize": 20
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Cian2001/irs_datasets/main/world_map.json",
    "format": {"property": "features"}
  },
  "projection": {"type": "mercator"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "properties.name",
      "from": {
        "key": "country",
        "fields": ["deaths_100k_people_year"],
        "data": {
          "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Cian2001/irs_datasets/main/Worldwide_deaths.csv",
          "format": {"type": "csv"}
        } 
      }
    }
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "geoshape",
    "fill": "#eee",
    "stroke": "#141010",
    "strokeWidth": 0.5
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "deaths_100k_people_year",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"scheme": "oranges"}
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "properties.name", "title": "Country"},
      {
        "field": "deaths_100k_people_year",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": "Deaths per 100k inhabitants"
      }
    ]
  },
  "config": {"mark": {"invalid": null}}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the fill.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  "title": {
    "text": "Worldwide Deaths on Roads per 100k inhabitants",
    "fontSize": 20
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Cian2001/irs_datasets/main/world_map.json",
    "format": {"property": "features"}
  },
  "projection": {"type": "mercator"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "properties.name",
      "from": {
        "key": "country",
        "fields": ["deaths_100k_people_year"],
        "data": {
          "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Cian2001/irs_datasets/main/Worldwide_deaths.csv",
          "format": {"type": "csv"}
        } 
      }
    }
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "geoshape",
    
    "stroke": "#141010",
    "strokeWidth": 0.5
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "deaths_100k_people_year",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"scheme": "oranges"}
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "properties.name", "title": "Country"},
      {
        "field": "deaths_100k_people_year",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": "Deaths per 100k inhabitants"
      }
    ]
  },
  "config": {"mark": {"invalid": null}}
}
```